# gdb: is it possible to cast/reinterpret a sequence in terms of a user-defined struct that isn't present in debug symbols

Tags: c, casting, gdb, debug-symbols

Below is the problem statement.  At the bottom is my actual question if you end up just skimming the problem statement.

*edit*

I forgot to mention: I'm linking with `--no-strip-discarded --discard-none`.  One of the object files (pre-link) gets matched by `grep` when I search for the type in question, but I'm not finding that string after dumping info from the object file with `nm`, `objdump`, and `readelf`.

---

I'm looking at some C code that uses an idiom along the lines of:

```
// somecode.h
typedef struct {
  // ...
  volatile unsigned char *member1;
} Type1_t;

typedef struct {
  unsigned int member1:16;
  unsigned int member2:32;
  unsigned int member3:16;
} Type2_t;
```

---

```
// somecode.c
// ...

void someFunction( Type1_t *type1Ptr ) {
  // ...
  doSomething( ((Type2_t*)type1Ptr->member1)->accessType2Member );
}
```

Please ignore any objections you might have to the coding style, that isn't my question.

In this case, no instance of `Type2_t` is ever instantiated, so as best I can tell the compiler determined it wasn't necessary to emit debugging information about the type.

I'm attempting to monitor the behavior of code using this casted data to track down a problem, but the best I've managed to do is get gdb to print the array in question as an array of bytes.  I can set a watch on the array with:

```
watch {char[12]}type1Ptr->member1
```

... but in addition to not actually displaying `member1, member2, & member3`, the pretty-printer for char arrays prints it out as a sequence of the form `\000\032\021`... etc (a note on this: I'm in solaris, and gdb 7.2 in Solaris has issues with **libiconv**, which gdb uses for code page translations.  I'm stuck with ISO-8859-1 for now.  I'm unsure if that's why it doesn't just print it as a sequence of hex characters), so I end up either having to print the contents with `display` or some other mechanism, then interpret the contents in my head.

---

What I'm looking for:

- Is there a way to make `gcc` emit all debug symbols, even if the type in question only shows up when doing a cast?

  - ... or if the type isn't used at all in actual code
- Can I just include a header in `gdb` somehow so the type is defined?
- This one is probably far fetched, but: does `gdb` have any facility for doing more complex casts than just casting to currently defined types?  As an example, is there a way to do something like the following

---

```
(gdb) print {struct { unsigned int:16 member1; unsigned int:32 member2;
          unsigned int:16 member3;} }( type1Ptr->member1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272558/can-we-define-a-new-data-type-in-a-gdb-session) takes care of the 2nd question, and sort of alleviates the need for #3.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer to the problem of type information not being available.  I added `-gstabs+` to my CFLAGS:

```
CFLAGS = (...) -ggdb3 ----> -gstabs+ <---- (...)
```

... and now gdb can tell me useful stuff about the type in question.

I'm still interested in answers to the other two questions, though, if anyone wants to take a shot at those.