# Specifying correct type by name in gdb when multiple types of same name exist

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I discovered that I get two different results when examining a variable, depending on whether I implicitly or explicitly use the type GDB understands that variable to be:

Navigate to my stack frame

`(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00007f6a4277e87d in PyCheckFile (fname=0x7f6a338704b8 "/usr/lib/debug/sbin", ctx=0x7f6a3803ddf8)
    at python-fd.c:2054
2054       pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(p_ctx->pDict, "check_file"); /* Borrowed reference */`

Print the what `p_ctx` points to, as GDB understands it, implicitly using whatever GDB knows about its type.

```
(gdb) print *p_ctx
$26 = {backup_level = 0, python_loaded = false, plugin_options = 0x0, module_path = 0x0, module_name = 0x0, 
  fname = 0x0, link = 0x0, object_name = 0x0, object = 0x0, interpreter = 0x7f6a3802bb10, pModule = 0x0, 
  pDict = 0x0, bpContext = 0x0}
```

Ask GDB for the name of the type

```
(gdb) whatis p_ctx
type = plugin_ctx *
```

Specify that type name explicitly when printing `p_ctx`, and we get a very different output.

```
(gdb) print * ( (plugin_ctx *) p_ctx )
$27 = {offset = 0, pfd = 0x0, plugin_options = 0x0, fname = 0x0, reader = 0x0, writer = 0x0, 
  where = '\000' <repeats 16 times>, "\020\273\002\070j\177", '\000' <repeats 26 times>, "\225\031\327Mj\177\000\000\240\000\000\000\000\000\000\000%\001\000\000\000\000\000\000@e\317Mj\177\000\000\370&\322Mj\177\000\000\375\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\260\234\337Mj\177\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@\ntBj\177\000\000\060\000\000\000\000\000\000\000*\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\177\000\000\000\000\000\000\000@\322\000\070j\177\000\000P\aCBj\177\000\000Ȋ\260\270i\225\fbЉ\342Mj\177\000\000\000\035c\001\000\000\000\000َ\372<\375\364\343\372\300\237\342Mj\177\000\000\000\337\325"..., replace = 0}
```

Ask GDB to tell us about types named plugin_ctx:

```
(gdb) info types ^plugin_ctx$
All types matching regular expression "^plugin_ctx$":

File bpipe-fd.c:
plugin_ctx;

File python-fd.c:
plugin_ctx;
```

Well there's our problem; we're in python-fd.c, and when we explicitly specify a type name, we get bpipe-fd's type instead!

As evidence:

```
(gdb) ptype p_ctx
type = struct plugin_ctx {
    int32_t backup_level;
    bool python_loaded;
    char *plugin_options;
    char *module_path;
    char *module_name;
    char *fname;
    char *link;
    char *object_name;
    char *object;
    PyThreadState *interpreter;
    PyObject *pModule;
    PyObject *pDict;
    PyObject *bpContext;
} *
```

compared to:

```
(gdb) ptype plugin_ctx
type = struct plugin_ctx {
    boffset_t offset;
    BPIPE *pfd;
    char *plugin_options;
    char *fname;
    char *reader;
    char *writer;
    char where[512];
    int replace;
}
```

So, when presented with multiple types named `plugin_ctx`, how to I tell gdb which one to use? I've tried:

```
(gdb) print * ( ('python-fd.c'::plugin_ctx *) p_ctx )
A syntax error in expression, near `*) p_ctx )'.
```

which obviously did not work. I have not found anything in GDB's manual on how to address this kind of disambiguation when it applies to types. So what's the preferred approach in this situation?

Comment: "multiple types named plugin_ctx". This is undefined behavior.

Comment: The different plugin_ctx types come from different TLUs. They're not present in the same place at the same time, source-wise.

Comment: Re-reading the language standards, this is actually OK in C and probably in C++ too. GDB is probably not too smart to handleit though.

Comment: GDB knows about both types, and handles the type correctly if specified implicitly. What I need to know is how to get GDB to select the correct type when I need to call it out by name. I.e I'm trying to examing a chunk of data a few frames up I believe to be of this type, but the (C++!) code I'm debugging plays fast and loose with void*, so I have to specify how to interpret the data if I want to examine it.

Comment: GDB does not necessarily have syntax to name the type in this situation.

Comment: Is there a means to create an alias GDB can use so I don't need to type out the whole struct type when expressing how to interpret the data?

Comment: Sure, define each alias in a separate source file, compile and link them into your program.

Comment: Clarification: Is there a way to define such an alias within the context of gdb?

If modifying the source were an option, I'd simply rename the types to eliminate the ambiguity. As it is, I'm broken into a crashed process on a prod server, digging around to find out why it's broken.

Comment: You don't need to modify anything, only add a new source. You can compile it into a shared lib and load it dynamically or with LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: Looks like there's a way to do that [at runtime within gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272558/can-we-define-a-new-data-type-in-a-gdb-session).

Comment: Yes this should work too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll flesh out this answer with examples as I get it working, but based on @n.m's feedback discussion on the core post and the information found within [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272558/can-we-define-a-new-data-type-in-a-gdb-session), here's a workaround:

Create an object file with the type you want, with an unambiguous name.

```
#include <Python.h>
struct plugin_ctx2 {
    int32_t backup_level;
    bool python_loaded;
    char *plugin_options;
    char *module_path;
    char *module_name;
    char *fname;
    char *link;
    char *object_name;
    char *object;
    PyThreadState *interpreter;
    PyObject *pModule;
    PyObject *pDict;
    PyObject *bpContext;
} ;
```

2. Using `gcc`'s `add-symbol-file` command, pull that object file into the running process.
3. You should now be able to use the new type.

Comment: I met the same problem, but my type is too complex to write one manually. I'm looking for other approaches to solve the problem. Too bad the people wrote code in this way, but we have to live with it.