# In gdb, How to typecast pointer to filespecif typedef

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I have files `a.c` and `b.c` which have different types with the same name:

#### a.c

```
struct map {
    int a;
}map_t;

//map_t * is use in file
```

#### b.c

```
struct map {
    int a;
    int b;
}map_t;

//map_t * is use in file
```

What I need ?
Here I know heap address that I want to typecast to particular map_t in a.c or b.c file. And then want to see values a or a,b (depend on typecast).

e.g.

```
Address = 0x1000
```

I want to see this address in typedef format of map_t define in a.c file.
I tried the following line in GDB but it fails to locate symbol `a.c::map_t`.

```
(GDB) p *(('a.c::map_t'*)0x1000)
No symbol "a.c::map_t" in current context.
```

How can I typecast address by map_t mention in a.c file ?
I'd also like to know how to do same in Python within GDB.

Note: I know which memory address of which type (I mean map_t from a.c or b.c). By raw memory I can work but want to see in proper GDB format.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you asking about C or C++? Please be sure to read on [asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thinking twice I'd say this is not possible, as you cannot have two types of the same name both being globally accessible at the same time by definition.

Comment: If being inside a function defined in `a.c` you get `map_t` defined in  `a.c` when casting to `map_t` and if in `b.c` you get the other one.

Comment: I do agree, but in gdb how to view heap allocated memory with typecast.

Comment: Just do `p *((T*) ptr)` with `ptr` being any valid address/pointer and  `T` a known, complete type. Or just use the `x ptr` command to dump memory content as address/pointer `ptr`.

Comment: To cast to types not known because being defined local to any other module you want to define a function to the module defining the type in question taking just a `void *`, put a break point into this function then use `call functionname(ptr)` to call the function, at the breakpoint it stops the type in question is known so you can do as proposed in my last comment.

Comment: Related: [Specifying correct type by name in gdb when multiple types of same name exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900427/specifying-correct-type-by-name-in-gdb-when-multiple-types-of-same-name-exist)

Comment: The questions linked links to another question which got this answer using a neat trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7273785/694576

Comment: Thanks alk, It solved my problem