# gdb : determining register content without source.

Tags: gdb

Navigating through a core file I am able to narrow it down to the specific point of failure and check the registers. 
Usually the register value is null which is a good indication that a null value was passed and causing a problem.

The question is what happens if there is a valid address?

Can the content of that address be determined without the source?

Without the source would it be possible to determine if the address points to a structure and if so would you be able to determine all attributes of the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can the content of that address be determined without the source?

Absolutely. Suppose the value of `$rax` is `0x12345678`. You can examine the value *at that address* with `(gdb) x/gx $rax`

> Without the source would it be possible to determine if the address points to a structure

In general: no. You could determine that the address is *not* pointing to a structure if the structure requires certain alignment, and the address is not properly aligned. Or if the address points to e.g. last 4 bytes of a page, and the next page is not mapped in, and the structure size is larger than 4 bytes.

> and if so would you be able to determine all attributes of the structure?

If you do believe that the address points to a structure, you can examine its contents. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273785/50617) on how to do that conveniently in GDB.