# GDB: manually inject debug symbols

Tags: debugging, gdb, debug-symbols, dwarf

I'm currently debugging a BIOS raw binary (no source code available), and I'd like to teach gdb debug symbols (eg. function offsets, local vars, stack params) that I've found out manually.

gdb can load various debug symbol file formats, but I didn't find anyting to teach 'em manually.

There're various tools for dumping debug info, but couldn't find anything that actually creates them from user defined input.

Does anyone have an idea how to do that ?

--thx

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't find anyting to teach 'em manually.

If by "manually" you mean typing debug info at the `(gdb)` prompt, I don't think that's possible (or a reasonable thing to try).

But you maybe looking for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273785/50617).

Comment: Yes, I mean adding them manually. I've got a binary-only image, which I cannot recompile.