# Unable to print a pointer in gdb. Am i facing a stack corruption

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, gdb

```
(gdb) p dst
$9 = (ad_opg__State *) 0x2995cef0
(gdb) p *dst
$10 = <incomplete type>
(gdb) p dst->state
There is no member named state.
(gdb)
(gdb) n
ad_trf::Serialize::serializeRecording (this=this@entry=0x859e00 <<ad_trf::RecordingFactory>::GetInstance()::instance+64>, src=0x2995f110) at Serialize.cpp:379
379                     dst->status = src->m_Status;
(gdb) p dst
$21 = (ad_opg__Recording *) 0x2995cef0
(gdb) p *dst
$22 = <incomplete type>
(gdb) p dst->state
There is no member named state.
(gdb) p *(0x2995cef0)
$23 = -2109491384
(gdb) 
(gdb) p/s  *(ad_opg__Recording *) 0x2995cef0
No symbol "ad_opg__Recording" in current context.
(gdb)
```

I feel the incomplete type is because these classes are in a separate module which hasn't got debug symbols enabled ( and i can't do it either because of lack of space in the filesystem. This is an embedded system with aarch64)

But i am interested to know if i am facing a stack corruption. Because i can atleast explore valgrind options instead.

In the snippet above, where I get this -

```
(gdb) p *(0x2995cef0)
$23 = -2109491384
```

Is this indicating stack corruption ?  I am not getting into details of ad_opg__State or ad_opg__Recording and what the relationship between them are. It would help to know if i am facing a stack corruption from this gdb trace. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You picked an address, and asked gdb to print what is at that address without telling gdb the type of data you expect to find. In response, gdb decided to pick a fallback type (probably `int`) instead of failing. Why would you interpret this as stack corruption?

Comment: If I were to look at your gdb transcript out of context, I would say it looks like a session with an executable linked from a mix of object files with debugging symbols and some without. You confirmed as much. Case closed? Why would you think "stack corruption" simply because gdb cannot access debugging information that does not exist?

Comment: If you have the struct definitions, you could try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273785/1983398).

Comment: Thanks Jamit and ssbssa. Understood your points made. But if i did not set any breakpoints and simply ran the program. It crashes and a backtrace gives this - 
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000007f8cba71ac in epoll_pwait () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000007f8dea0e90 in AdIpcBus::listen() () from ../lib/libadipc.so
#2  0x0000007f8dea10a0 in ?? () from ../lib/libadipc.so
#4  0x0000007fd4b517d8 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb)
See the last line. Would that suggest a stack corruption? or is gdb unsure ?