# "No struct type named foo" when struct unused

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Assume I have C code that includes this include file:

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
};

#define FOO ((struct foo*)(0x123))
```

The program is compiled with `-ggdb3`.

When `FOO` is used at runtime anywhere, I can use it also in the debugging console. But when it isn't (but the include *is* included), the macro `#define FOO` works, but the unused definition of `struct foo` is unknown to gdb:

```
(gdb) p FOO
No struct type named foo.
(gdb) p FOOx
No symbol "FOOx" in current context.
```

How can I make gdb include also unused structures in its debugging information?

Comment: Have you tried [-fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we define a new data type in a GDB session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7272558/can-we-define-a-new-data-type-in-a-gdb-session)