# Is it available to define a class or struct in user-defined-commands of GDB?

Tags: struct, gdb, command, user-defined

In a user-defined commands of GDB, is it possible to define a struct? If not, any workaround?

e.g.

```
define myFunc
   # something like this
   typedef struct {
     int32_t f1;
     int32_t f2;
     ...
   } MyObj;
end
```

If use "typedef struct" in GDB, it would give below prompt:

```
Undefined command: "typedef". Try "help".
```

Comment: The usual way to do this is via [`add-symbol-file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273785/1983398).

Comment: http://xyproblem.info seems relevant here.

Comment: add-symbol-file should work, thanks ssbssa!